# Oracle problems with CTE

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, common-table-expression

I've implemented your changes and trying to make a few more. My goal is to issue an update on the access_history table and set processed = 1 for those records, which created the set of emp_attendance records.

When I try to find the MIN(ts) and MAX(ts) I get the following error

ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

When I add a group by I get a different error. I posted the code with the error and was wondering if you can tell me how to accomplish removing the error and issue the update in the same query.

```
-- Drop table emp_info purge:
-- Drop table locations purge;
-- Drop table access_histoty purge;
-- Drop table emp_attendance purge;

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';

CREATE TABLE employees
(
   employee_id NUMBER(6),
   first_name VARCHAR2(20),
   last_name VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
   card_num varchar2(10)  NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE employees
     ADD ( CONSTRAINT employee_id_pk
   PRIMARY KEY (employee_id));


Insert into employees values (1, 'Mike', 'Jones', 'AAA1');

Insert into employees values (2, 'Jane', 'Doe', 'BBB2');


Insert into employees values (3, 'Paul', 'Smith', 'CCC3');

Insert into employees values (4, 'John', 'Henry', 'DDD4');



 Create table locations(
   location_id NUMBER(4),
   location_name varchar2(30),
   location_type char(1));

 -- A=access T=Time & Attendance 

ALTER TABLE locations 
     ADD ( CONSTRAINT lication_id_pk
   PRIMARY KEY (location_id));



Insert into locations values (101, 'South Front Door 1', 'T');

  Insert into locations values (102, 'South Front Door 2', 'T');

  Insert into locations values (103, 'East Back Door 1', 'T');

   Insert into locations values (104, 'East Back Door 2', 'T');

   Insert into locations values (105,'Computer Room', 'A');

   Insert into locations values (106,'1st Floor North',  'A');


Create table access_history(
   employee_id NUMBER(6), 
   card_num varchar2(10),
   location_id number(4),
   Access_date date,
   ts timestamp default systimestamp,
   processed NUMBER(1) default 0
);


INSERT INTO access_history
( employee_id, card_num,
   location_id, Access_date )
 VALUES (1, 'AAA1', 101,    TO_DATE('06212020 21:02:04',  'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS'));


   -- TYpe T no previous data for this
   -- empid record INSERT empid, 
    -- start  time ONLY in table below 
     -- and  update last_start_date  
     -- with DATETIME.



INSERT INTO access_history
( employee_id, card_num,
   location_id, Access_date )
 VALUES (1, 'AAA1', 102,    TO_DATE('06212020 23:52:14',  'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS'));


  -- Type T record empid, start_time
  --  set update end_time only in
  -- emp_attendance.



INSERT INTO access_history
( employee_id, card_num,
   location_id, Access_date )
 VALUES (2, 'BBB2', 103,    TO_DATE('06212020 08:32:35',  'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS'));


 -- TYpe T  INSERT empid, start 
 -- time ONLY in emp_attendance.  
 -- update last_start_date with 
 --  DATETIME on emp_info table



INSERT INTO access_history
( employee_id, card_num,
   location_id, Access_date )
 VALUES (2, 'BBB2', 102,    TO_DATE('06212020 15:39:05',  'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS'));


-- Type T record empid, start_time 
--  set, update end_time only in
-- emp_attendance.


INSERT INTO access_history
( employee_id, card_num,
   location_id, Access_date )
 VALUES (3, 'CCC3', 103,    TO_DATE('06212020 15:39:05',  'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS'));


 -- TYpe T  INSERT empid, start 
 -- time ONLY in emp_attendance.  
 -- update last_start_date with 
 --  DATETIME on emp_info table



INSERT INTO access_history
( employee_id, card_num,
   location_id, Access_date )
 VALUES (3, 'CCC3', 105,    TO_DATE('06212020 18:19:55',  'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS'));


-- Type A record don't do anything to 
-- emp_attendance.



INSERT INTO access_history
( employee_id, card_num,
   location_id, Access_date )
 VALUES (4, 'DDD4', 102,    TO_DATE('06212020 08:49:35',  'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS'));

--  single record with no pair. Set
-- end_date to start_date if end_date
-- is NULL



INSERT INTO access_history
( employee_id, card_num,
   location_id, Access_date )
 VALUES (3, 'CCC3', 104,    TO_DATE('06222020 04:04:35',  'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS'));


-- Type T record empid, start_time 
--  set, update end_time only in
-- emp_attendance.


 CREATE TABLE  emp_attendance    
  (seq_num NUMBER(10),
   employee_id NUMBER(6),
   start_date DATE,
   end_date DATE,
   create_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
   );

   Create sequence emp_attendance_seq;

   insert into emp_attendance.   
     (seq_num, 
       employee_id, 
       start_date, 
      end_date)

   with

   -- error capturing min,max ts
   --
   prep (min_ts, max_ts, employee_id, start_date, rn, end_date) as (

     select MIN(ts), MAX(ts), employee_id, access_date

        , row_number()      over (partition by card_num order by access_date)

      , lead(access_date) over (partition by card_num order by access_date)

   from   access_history

 where  location_id in ( select location_id

                     from   locations

                      where  location_type = 'T'

                  )

                  AND processed = 0

  )

   select emp_attendance_seq.nextval,

      employee_id,

     start_date,

   nvl(end_date, start_date)

  from prep

 where  mod(rn, 2) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

> In the CTE below I am trying to INSERT the records from the SELECT into the table emp_attendance but I cant seem work.

It is easier to assist if you described what's wrong with your attempt. Because, the way it is, it just lacks the `INSERT INTO` statement, a sequence call and the `NVL` function - at least, that's what I understood.

```
SQL> insert into emp_attendance (seq_num, employee_id, start_date, end_Date)
  2  with
  3    prep (employee_id, start_date, rn, end_date) as (
  4      select employee_id, access_date
  5           , row_number()      over (partition by card_num order by access_date)
  6           , lead(access_date) over (partition by card_num order by access_date)
  7      from   access_history
  8      where  location_id in ( select location_id
  9                          from   locations
 10                          where  location_type = 'T'
 11                        )
 12    )
 13  select emp_attendance_seq.nextval,
 14         employee_id,
 15         start_date,
 16         nvl(end_date, start_date)
 17  from prep
 18  where  mod(rn, 2) = 1;

4 rows created.

SQL> select * From emp_attendance;

   SEQ_NUM EMPLOYEE_ID START_DATE          END_DATE
---------- ----------- ------------------- -------------------
         1           1 21.06.2020 21:02:04 21.06.2020 23:52:14
         2           2 21.06.2020 08:32:35 21.06.2020 15:39:05
         3           3 21.06.2020 15:39:05 22.06.2020 04:04:35
         4           4 21.06.2020 08:49:35 21.06.2020 08:49:35

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Initially I had the INSERT statement above the SELECT and was getting an error missing keyword SELECT. I than moved the code to where you placed it via cut and paste and I was getting syntax errors. No doubt I missed some text. I have one last question left on my list and would like your expertise. What would be the best way not to reprocess the same records again when more data is added to access_history table

Comment: You're welcome. As of *not reprocessing the same records*, I guess that you'd include NOT EXISTS clause. In other words: insert rows that don't exist in the table (yet). Another option is NOT IN (which is usually easier to understand).

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I was hoping you can take a look at my updated problem. Your changes work great but I needed more functionality and I'm running into syntax errors

Comment: Changes you made make no sense. Why do you need min/max of TS, if you don't do anything with them? I suggest you to start from beginning - see what you have in those tables, and make sure you know what you want as a result. Then start coding, step by step.

Comment: I do need them as rows are constantly being added to the access_history table. I want to construct the following query once the INSERT is completed...   update access_history 
  set processed = 1
  where ts >= min_ts and
             ts <= max_ts